# No option for "mobile network" on Dell Venue 8

Tags: settings, internet, mobile-network, mobile-data

My friend has bought new "Dell Venue 8 3830" tablet with Android JellyBean 4.3.

Now we want to connect a 3g dongle (D-Link) via a micro-usb cable which came with it.

When i connect the dongle to the device the dongle shows solid green light (which probably means connected), but when i go up in settings of the tablet i dont see an option to turn on and use the device.

All the blog i read tells to enable the "Mobile Network" option in settings; But on this device theres no such option.

```
Wireless Settings
      - Wifi
      - B/T
      - Hotspot
      - Data Usage
      - More...
             - Airplane Mode
             - VPN
             - Tethering
```

Comment: (1) Can you post a link to the blog? (2) I'm assuming you want to use the 3G dongle so that the tablet gets 3G access (as a consumer of data). Is that right?

Comment: 1) http://androidtipguys.com/forum/setting-up-mobile-network-android-tablet-658.html is one of them

2) Yes

Comment: NO it does not have a sim card slot.

Comment: If there is no SIM card slot, then how do you expect to have an option `Mobile networks`. It is meant for networking via sim card.

Answer (score -1):

Check `Settings` → `Wireless & networks` → `More` → `Mobile networks` → `Data enabled` to enable it

See [user guide](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_tab_mob/esuprt_tablets/dell-venue-8_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf)

Comment: The OP states that the "Mobile Network" option is not there.